# c++ Linux compilation error

Tags: c++, linux, set

I am getting following error while compiling in linux.

```
file.cxx:283:9: error: reference to ‘multimap’ is ambiguous
file.cxx:273:47: error: candidates are: std::multimap, std::basic_string > multimap
```

->piece of sample code is

```
static std::multimap<std::string,std::string> multimap;   //line no. 273
//
void foo()
{
    if (multimap.size() == 0)
    {
        multimap.insert( std::pair< std::string, std::string >( "A" , "B" ) );
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have `using namespace std;` at the top of your file?

Comment: Besides what the answers say: General (and easy) advice: don't use identifiers with the same name as standard library components.

Comment: @kebs there's no reason for that kind of advice. Instead, don't use `using namespace std` or `using std::whatever`.

Comment: Oh, and how about "don't use static variables if you can avoid it".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have `using namespace std;` in the file. That means your compiler already knows "multimap", which you are trying to define again, in which case the compiler doesn't know which one you mean.

Answer (score 0):

There is a member `function` in std and you inserted it into your namespace. Avoid using `using namespace std;` you can import what you need this way:

`using std::multimap;`

`using std::string;`